# Hard time printing struct members with a function

Tags: c, function, struct, printf, garbage

I'm new to C and I'm developing this basic project while I study it, to help me fixate things... so please, bear with me if my code still looks kind of stupid.

That being said, I'm having trouble with a function to print struct members.
I've created a function to register book details and a separate one for printing said details.

If I print the details within the registerBook function, they are printed correctly.

However, when I call the method printBook, all I get is "garbage". And it's always the same characters,

The code is as follows:

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Books {
    char title[30];
    char author[20];
    int book_id[10];
    char subject[50];
} Books;

int main() {

    struct Books Book1;
    struct Books Book2;

    registerBook(Book1);
    printBook(Book1);
    registerBook(Book2);
    printBook(Book2);

    int exit = 0;
    while(exit == 0) {
        scanf("%p", exit);
    }

    return 0;
}

void printBook(struct Books a){
    printf("\nTitle: %s", a.title);
    printf("\nAuthor: %s", a.author);
    printf("\nISBN: %d", a.book_id);
    printf("\nSubject: %s", a.subject);
}

void registerBook(struct Books a){
    printf("\nTitle?");
    scanf("%s", &a.title);
    printf("\nAuthor?");
    scanf("%s", &a.author);
    printf("\nISBN?");
    scanf("%d", &a.book_id);
    printf("\nSubject?");
    scanf("%s", &a.subject);
}
```

---

All I get is:

---

> Title?one
>
> Author?two
>
> ISBN?3
>
> Subject?four
>
> Title: ç Author: ` ISBN: 6356340 Subject: Ç@ Title?five
>
> Author?six
>
> ISBN?7
>
> Subject?eight
>
> Title: &Ý=w¬8wÝ=wÃÊpï Author: ISBN: 6356340 Subject:

---

Could someone please advise?

Comment: Remove the &s from the scanf functions in registerBook. The function expects a char * which will have the same value as the array.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick reply, Alden. 
Unfortunately, it remains the same for printBook().

Comment: Thanks, I've tried it but I'm still getting the same characters as output. If I print a.title, for example, within registerBook();, it prints correctly. But when I try to printf in main, it gives exactly the same "garbage" as printBook();.

Comment: the first part of the posted code, before the function: `main()` is both defining a struct AND declaring an instance of that struct (which, unfortunately, uses the same name as the struct.)   The instance of the struct is completely unnecessary and should be removed.

Comment: When passing parameters, the passing of a whole struct is a very poor programming practice.  Just pass a pointer to the struct  Then write the sub functions to expect a pointer to a struct rather than the whole struct and to access the fields of the struct, off that pointer

Comment: `exit` is a well known function, and was brought into the program via the `#include <stdlib.h>`  statement.  User code should NEVER use system function names as variable names.  Suggest change the variable name from `exit` to something like: `done`.

Comment: when calling the function: `scanf()` 1) always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.  2) when using the format specifier '%s', always include a MAX LENGTH modifier that is one less than the length of the input buffer, so the input/user cannot overrun the input buffer (which would result in undefined behaviour and lead to a seg fault event.)

Comment: the code contains several 'magic numbers.  10, 20, 30, 50  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.  Suggest using a `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: the `scanf()` format specifier: '%p` is for addresses, not any other value.

Comment: in C, when referencing an array name, the name degrades to the address of the first byte fo the array,  So this kind of line: `scanf("%s", &a.title)` is not correct as it is passing scanf the address of the address of `a.title`.  What should be done for an array is: `scanf( "%s", a.title );`  (however, remember that a "%s" format specifier should have a 'max length' modifier that is one less than the length of the input field, and the returned value should be checked, so should be: `if( 1 != scanf( "% 29s", a.title ) ) { perror( "scanf for title failed"); }`

Comment: the '%s' format specifier, when used with `scanf()` will stop at any `white space` so if the title or author contain any space(s) the operation will fail.

Comment: if you correct the code to pass point to struct rather than the whole struct, then inside the functions use: `a->title` and similar statements.

Comment: in the function: `printBook()`, the last call to `printf()` should have a trailing '\n' in the format string, so the output will be immediately printed.  (the code could also use: `fflush( stdout );`

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99` )

Comment: the code is missing the prototypes for the functions: `registerBook()` and `printfBook()`, so the compiler will make assumptions about the parameter types and about the returned type, Which will not match the actual function signatures.  The result is the compiler will output several warning messages AND produce the wrong code.

Comment: to keep the terminal open, at the end of the program, use something like: `int ch; while( (ch = getchar()) != EOF && '\n' != ch ); getchar();`

Comment: Thanks for the knowledge shared, @user3629249. As I said, I'm brand new to C and was just testing what I've learned so far. I think I've found what I need, here: http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex16.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the registerBook function you should pass the parameters by reference and not by value so you can keep the changes after the function ends.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Books {
    char title[30];
    char author[20];
    int book_id;
    char subject[50];
} Books;

void printBook(struct Books a){
    printf("\nTitle: %s", a.title);
    printf("\nAuthor: %s", a.author);
    printf("\nISBN: %d", a.book_id);
    printf("\nSubject: %s", a.subject);
}

void registerBook(struct Books* a){
    printf("\nTitle?");
    scanf(" %s", a->title);
    printf("\nAuthor?");
    scanf(" %s", a->author);
    printf("\nISBN?");
    scanf(" %d", &a->book_id);
    printf("\nSubject?");
    scanf(" %s", a->subject);
}



int main() {

    struct Books Book1;
    struct Books Book2;

    registerBook(&Book1);
    printBook(Book1);
    registerBook(&Book2);
    printBook(Book2);


    return 0;
}
```

I didn't include your exit loop as it is something that has nothing to do with your problem here.

Comment: Thanks, George Bou! That fixed the problem! Now I get what I was doing wrong, there. :) The only thing that's still wrong is the book_id, which is returning the same number always, no matter what I write.

Comment: Oh, book_id cannot be an array =X my mistake. Thanks again !